# Cheap one-way flight from Europe to South America?

Tags: air-travel, europe, flight-search-engines, south-america

Very flexible long time traveler but not very familiar with the cheap routes between Europe and South America.

Would be happy to learn about flight routes (from/to airport), airlines, times of year etc.

If it helps narrow things down a bit, I was thinking of heading of either Portugal or Spain around the end of summer (September?) towards anywhere in South America (Colombia?).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor the [flyertalk mileage run deals](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/mileage-run-deals-372/) forum. Also, the [cheap city pair](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/mileage-run-deals/1733879-good-deals-economy-class-excellent-fares-between-certain-city-pairs-2016-a-7.html) thread.

Answer (score 2):

Besides trying your hand at searching through the usual suspects (Adioso, matrix.itasoftware.com, google flights, hipmunk, etc.), which is going to give you the actual cost of flying, I've found the following:

It's possible to get a *roundtrip* on most major airlines between a few big South American cities and a few European cities for as low as 500 euros. In South America, you likely would fly from Sao Paulo, Rio or Buenos Aires. In Europe, Lisbon, Madrid, but also sometimes Amsterdam.

Last year, I managed to get a KLM flight between Amsterdam and Curacao for little over half the cost of a round trip. That sounds great, but getting off Curacao to the mainland is annoyingly expensive.

The only airline I'm aware of that regularly sells one way tickets between Europe and South America without charging an arm and a leg (but still charging noticeably more than half) is Royal Air Maroc.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use SkyScanner to identify a few low-cost routes, then matrix.itasoftware.com to find a likely good date for one of those routes, and then, check around that date on kayak.com, momondo.com, and adioso.com

And when I think I've found the best deal, check the airline's website to make sure.  Sometimes it is a little less.

This doesn't always get the best price, though.  The terms for baggage vary so much that it is a major research pain to ensure that baggage fees don't reverse the price difference.

Answer (score -1):

You could try a site like skyscanner, or along those lines.  I've had experience with booking really cheap flights from at least inside the US to different locations.  Also the site allows you to search the whole month

Comment: Often I wish SkyScanner would let me search from the middle of one month to the middle of the next.  And I wonder why sometimes it shows nothing.